# How to increment and decrement between two values

Tags: algorithm, iteration, pseudocode

This is embarrassing, but:

Let say I want to add 1 to x until it reaches 100. At that point I then want to subtract 1 from x until it reaches 1. Then I want to add 1 to x until it reaches 100, and so on.

Could someone provide some simple pseudocode to this question that is making me feel especially dumb.

Thanks :)

---

**EDIT 1**

Apologies! I made my example too simple. I actually will be incrementing using a random number at each iteration, so responses that require (x == 100) would not work as x will surely go above 100 and below 1.

Comment: could you elaborate your edit with an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int ceiling = 100;
int floor = 1;
int x = 1;
int step = GetRandomNumber(); //assume this isn't 0

while(someArbitraryCuttoffOrAlwaysTrueIDK) {
    while(x + step <= ceiling) {
        x += step;
    }
    while(x - step >= floor) {
        x -= step;
    }
}
```

Or, being more concise (at the risk of being less clear):

```
while(someArbitraryCuttoffOrAlwaysTrueIDK) {
    while((step > 0  && x + step <= ceiling) || (step < 0 && x + step >= floor)) 
    {
        x += step;
    }
    step = step * -1;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
while(someArbitraryCuttoffOrAlwaysTrueIDK) {
    if((step > 0  && x + step > ceiling) || (step < 0 && x + step < floor)) 
    {
        step = step * -1;
    }
    x += step;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is math way:

```
for(int i=0;i<10000000;i++)
  print(abs(i%200-100))
```

**Algo's way:**

```
int i = 1;
while(1)
{
 while(i<100)print(i++);
 while(i>1)print(--i);
}
```

**Random updated:**

```
int i = 1;
while(1)
{
 while(i<100)print(i=min(100,i+random()));
 while(i>1)print(i=max(1,i-random()));
}
```

Comment: For the first one, you get the sequence 100->0->100->... instead of 1->100->1->...

Answer (score 0):

**C#:**

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int someVarToIncreaseDecrease = 0;
bool increasing = true;

while(true) {
    int addSubtractInt = rnd.Next(someUpperBound);

    if (increasing && (someVarToIncreaseDecrease + addSubtractInt >= 100)) 
       increasing = false;
    else if (!increasing && (someVarToIncreaseDecrease - addSubtractInt < 0)) 
       increasing = true;

    if (increasing) {
       someVarToIncreaseDecrease += addSubtractInt;
    }
    else {
       someVarToIncreaseDecrease -= addSubtractInt;
    }
}
```